# Adobe Air Mobile (iOS, Android) and Incoming Phone Calls

Tags: android, ios, air, phone-call

I'm looking into handling Audio interruptions (incoming phone calls, calendar or clock events) in my Air application.  The target OS are iOS and Android.

I already have a working implementation for pausing and resuming my application when such event occurs, derived from Apple's guidelines for handling such interruptions ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html))

Does anyone knows which events I can leverage in the AIR platform?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the listeners for

```
addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, activateListener);
addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivateListener);
```

might be the ones to use.